# Delete only non max records of a group

Tags: sql, max

I am trying to do something like the following

```
delete PreOrder
where preorderid not in (
select preorderid
from PreOrder p1
inner join (select max(OrderDt) OrderDt, preorderid
from preorder group by preorderid) p2 on
p1.preorderid=p2.preorderid
where p1.preorder in (1,2,3,4,5)
```

I am just try to delete the record if there are dupes of just those. I got the max working, but how to delete just from those records that has that preorderid

Comment: What database are you using.  Please tag the question correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```
Delete p1
from PreOrder p1
left join (select max(OrderDt) OrderDt, preorderid
from preorder group by preorderid) p2 on
p1.preorderid=p2.preorderid
and p1.OrderDt = p2.OrderDt
where p2.preorderid is null and p1.preorderid in (1,2,3,4,5)
```